# Visual Studio 2019 - empty Reference Manager

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I am struggling with adding references in a Visual Studio 2019 project. I need to use commands from a .dll library in my source code. The problem is, that the Reference Manager sees literally nothing (see below).

[Reference Manager - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPw2u.png)

How to get over this issue?

EDIT:

In general, the code consists of two lines printing "START" and "END" and a bunch of commands from the .dll/.lib file between them. This is what I am getting after debugging and running the program: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN6DM.png) The program prints those two messages but does not execute the commands. That is the message I am getting in the output window: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfd4c.png)
This is the call stack (not sure if that helps anyway): [Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG6Nz.png)

Comment: Do you get same from all your projects?

Comment: A C++ project can only add a reference to another C++ project that generates a .lib file.  If the solution contains only one C++ project then inevitably the list is empty.  Use Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies to name that .lib file.

Comment: @jdweng - nope, just this one.

Comment: Are the other projects c++ or c#?  The project yoiu are using is c++, not c#.

Answer (score 0):

The Add Reference dialog box lists the libraries that you can reference. The Projects tab lists the projects in the current solution and any libraries they reference. Only when the library file and the project are in the same solution, we could directly link the library file by "add reference".

If they are not in the same solution, I suggest you could follow the following steps to add the DLL import library to your project:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

4,Add a Post-Build Event to your project, to add a command that copies the DLL to your build output directory（ Properties > Build Events > Post-Build Event ）

Comment: I am not sure how to properly do the 4. point. What command should it be?

Comment: @Tomasz If you followed the directions to put your client project in a separate solution from the DLL project, then enter this command:

`copy /y /d "..\..\..\$(IntDir)XXX.dll" "$(OutDir)”`

If your DLL and client projects are in the same solution directory, then enter this command:

`xcopy /y /d "..\..\..\$(IntDir)XXX.dll" "$(OutDir)"`

Comment: @Tomasz Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.

Answer (score -1):

In vs2019 follow this steps:

1. Click 'Project' menu
2. Click 'Add Reference'
3. sub menu Click'Browse...' button

Comment: Unfortunately, in his attached photo he does not have the option to browse.  I'm assuming this is because it is a C++ project.